# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows()

Tags: codeigniter, easyphp

Tenho as seguintes linhas em **CodeIgniter**: Linha 217

```
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in
>   arquivo.php on line 217

O que pode ser? Anteriormente funcionava perfeitamente...  Só que reinstalei a maquina e agora deu esse problema. Estou usando o **CodeIgniter** e o **EasyPHP** para testes.

Se eu trocar a linha por `if (count($query) == 0)`, vai funcionar certinho, porém, ai eu teria que trocar em todos os lugares que eu uso o `num_rows`, e dentro do servidor funciona certinho.

Comment: poste a linha da variável `$query`

Comment: Essa linha foi retirada do Session.php do codeigniter, nesta situação estou verificando se o usuário existe... porém, se eu trocar como eu disse na questão, usar o count, funciona... mas eu teria que usar o count em tudo...

Comment: Pra começar, ``$query->num_rows()`` é diferente de ``count($query)``. Primeiro entenda o que está fazendo, você só está tentando tudo sem nem entender o que está acontecendo. Sua conexão com o banco de dados está funcionando corretamente?

Comment: Sim, está normal sim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que a variável **$query** muito provavelmente recebeu o valor **false** do retorno da consulta no banco de dados. Quando você tenta acessar o método **num_rows()** ele diz que você está tentando acessar um método de uma variável que não é objeto. Como no PHP uma variável tem seu tipo definido em tempo de execução, **$query** ora pode ser objeto e ora pode ser booleano. Você pode chamar um `var_dump($query)` para ver qual valor ele recebeu.

Para evitar que o erro seja jogado na cara do usuário, você pode fazer a seguinte sequência de verificações:

```
try {
    $query = ...;
    if ($query === false) {
        throw new Exception();
    } else if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    /* ESCREVA AQUI A LÓGICA DE TRATAMENTO DOS DADOS */

} catch (Exception $e) {
    return null;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)